# How to subtract one huge list from another efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, performance, collections

I have a very long list of Ids (integers) that represents all the items that are currently in my database:

```
var idList = GetAllIds();
```

I also have another huge generic list with items to add to the database:

```
List<T> itemsToAdd;
```

Now, I would like to remove all items from the generic list whose Id is already in the idList. 
Currently idList is a simple array and I subtract the lists like this:

```
itemsToAdd.RemoveAll(e => idList.Contains(e.Id));
```

I am pretty sure that it could be a lot faster, so what datatypes should I use for both collections and what is the most efficient practice to subtract them?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to know how to stream/enumerate this as well, if possible...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Transform temporarily `idList` to an `HashSet<T>` and use the same method i.e.:

```
items.RemoveAll(e => idListHash.Contains(e.Id));
```

it should be much faster

Comment: Thanks - that performs a lot faster indeed and is what I did!

Answer (score 23):

LINQ could help:

```
itemsToAdd.Except(idList)
```

Your code is slow because `List<T>.Contains` is `O(n)`. So your total cost is `O(itemsToAdd.Count*idList.Count)`.

You can make idList into a `HashSet<T>` which has `O(1)` `.Contains`. Or just use the Linq `.Except` extension method which does it for you.

Note that `.Except` will also remove all duplicates from the left side. i.e. new `int[]{1,1,2}.Except(new int[]{2})` will result in just `{1}` and the second 1 was removed. But I assume it's no problem in your case because IDs are typically unique.

Comment: Note that this will also exclude any duplicates from `itemsToAdd`. Whether or not that's a problem is up to the OP (I suspect not since they're already using `RemoveAll` in their example).

Comment: +1 and thanks for the excellent explanation! I now build idList as Hashset<int> but can't use .Except() because itemsToAdd is of type List/HashSet<T> and idList is of type HashSet<int>. It is alot faster though and satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming** the following premises are true:

- `idList` and `itemsToAdd` may not contain duplicate values
- you are using the .NET Framework 4.0

you could use a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) this way:

```
var itemsToAddSet = new HashSet(itemsToAdd);
itemsToAddSet.ExceptWith(idList);
```

According to the documentation the [ISet<T>.ExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382043.aspx) method is pretty efficient:

> This method is an O(n) operation,
>   where n is the number of elements in
>   the *other* parameter.

In your case `n` is the number of items in `idList`.

Comment: The problem is that itemsToAdd would be of type HashSet<T> and idList is of type HashSet<int>. Therefore I can't call ExceptWith on these two and needed to transform idList into a Hashset<T> which would consume a lot of memory.

Comment: `idList` doesn't have to be a `HashSet<int>`, you just need to create a HashSet out of `itemsToAdd`. You'll then pass `idList` to `HashSet<T>.ExceptWith` as an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two `HashSet<int>`s.
Note that they're unique and unordered.