# Exclude a collection from another by lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda

This is my type:

```
public class myType
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
 }
```

And there is 2 collection of this type:

```
List<myType> FristList= //fill ;
List<myType> Excludelist= //fill;
```

And I need to exclude `Excludelist` from `FristList` something like the following:

```
List<myType> targetList = 
FirstList.Where(m=>m.Id  not in (Excludelist.Select(t=>t.Id));
```

What is your suggestion about the exact lambda expression of the above query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subtract one huge list from another efficiently in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091922/how-to-subtract-one-huge-list-from-another-efficiently-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Three options. One without any changes:

```
var excludeIds = new HashSet<int>(excludeList.Select(x => x.Id));
var targetList = firstList.Where(x => !excludeIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Alternatively, either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and use:

```
var targetList = firstList.Except(excludeList).ToList();
```

Or write an `IEqualityComparer<MyType>` which compares by IDs, and use:

```
var targetList = firstList.Except(excludeList, comparer).ToList();
```

The second and third options are definitely nicer IMO, particularly if you need to do this sort of work in various places.

Comment: I agree the latter options are cleaner, but won't the first option perform better in cases where `excludeList` has a non-trivial number of items?

Comment: @richardtallent: Nope, because `Except` builds a hash set internally anyway.