# Getting the element missing in a second list of different type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two differents type of List :

```
List<class1> list1;
List<class2> list2;
```

Both entities have a same property called `Id`.
`list1` contains 10 elements and `list2` has 200.

I need to get the list of element in `list1` who are not in `list2` according to the field `Id`.

I know there is a Linq operator called [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is only for two elements of the same type and assume that all field of the entities are equals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude a collection from another by lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748138/exclude-a-collection-from-another-by-lambda)

Comment: Have a look at Jon Skeets answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748138/exclude-a-collection-from-another-by-lambda

Comment: This article assume that both list are of the same type, isn't it ?

Comment: Another choice is to use an abstract class/interface that both `Class1` and `Class2` implement (With the method for getting the ID), then you could convert the lists to a list of the abstract class type and run your check there on both lists

Comment: Also the first part of Jon Skeets answer doesn't care on the type, as it collects the IDs into one list and then uses that to exclude from the 2nd list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer presented will not scale well as the sizes of your lists grow. A simple change to make it more  performant is to turn the exception list into a HashSet. If the Id property is an integer, it would look something like this:

```
var exceptIds = new HashSet<int>(list2.Select(y => y.Id).Distinct());
var unmatched = list1.Where(x => !exceptIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
unmatched.Dump(); // LinqPad method, to see output
```

If the type of Id is something else, simply substitute it into the first line as the generic type parameter.

Alternately, you can produce the same unmatched output using a left join technique, much like a "find unmatched records" query in SQL.

```
var unmatched = (from item in list1
                join item2 in list2 on item.Id equals item2.Id into grp
                from x in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where x == null
                select item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
var exceptIds = list2.Select(y => y.Id).Distinct().ToList();
list1 = list1.Where(x => !exceptIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: It works fine. Is there any performance issues with this linq operation ?